# 'x' occurs twice in a nested scoping construct, in a way that is likely to be an error

Tags: warning-messages, notebooks

I am defining the following innocent looking function (which defines a linear function passing through two given points):

```
lin[a_,b_,x_] := (a[[2]]-x)/(a[[2]]-a[[1]]) b[[1]] + (x-a[[1]])/(a[[2]]-a[[1]]) b[[2]] ;
```

In the notebook, the 'x' is occasionally shown in red.
When I pass the cursor on it, I get the following message:

"'x' occurs twice in a nested scoping construct, in a way that is likely to be an error"

The function works fine, and the red marking sometimes disappears, and sometimes comes back.
I didn't manage to pinpoint when it appears and when it goes away. Sometimes, there are definitions
preceding the definition of 'lin', but they are all syntactically correct.

Any idea what is going on?

I am using

12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)

Comment: I can see no reason for that expression to produce a warning message or highlighting.  It does not in version 10.1.  Perhaps a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Just as Mr.Wizard I also don't see that problem in 12.1 in a fresh notebook containing just this expression in one cell. Are you seeing this problem when you put just this line in an extra cell in a new notebook? I would suspect that the root cause most proably issomething else within the affected notebook.

I can see e.g. red `x` plus the warning if I enter right before that line **in the same cell** something like `f[x_]:=`. If I add something to this so it reads `f[x_]:=1;` the `x` will not be read again:

[image]

So far I think that is the intended behavior as the unfinished expression will be continued at the next line. Once it is finished the next line starts a new expression. This handling of line-continuation within one cell is something I don't like and find a permanent source of potential errors. So I try to avoid it wherever I can by only placing one expression per cell whenever possible...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't see the red x when the definition of 'lin' is by itself. But it does appear when I add commands before this definition, and sometimes it does not go away even if the preceding definitions are complete and syntactical. Furthermore, it stays even after I execute the commands and get no error messages. It is just a bit annoying.

Comment: Well, if it persists when the expressions above are complete I would consider that as a bug. The other cases are, as you said, just annoying. Thus my remark that I try to use one cell per expression. Because of the special nature of notebook expressions when writing code I think the best approach is to put one definition in one cell which avoids many of these glitches. It also makes it easier to navigate and move within the notebook in my opinion.